# View Shared Office 365 Calendar on iOS

Tags: ios, calendar, office-365

I'm trying to help someone who uses Office 365 at work with a Mac. Right now, she has to use the official Outlook app on all of her devices (MacBook, iOS, Apple Watch, etc.), but she'd like to be able to use the native Apple apps instead. This seems to work fine for everything except for shared calendars.

On the Mac Calendar app, you can set up delegate calendars easily, but I don't see a way to do that on iOS. Is there a way to view a shared (non-public) calendar on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the native OS X and iOS apps do not understand delegate calendars. Microsoft implemented them as a non-standard calendar extending the basic CalDAV format, so you would need to wait for Apple to code to Microsoft's standard or use another app to view those. (I can't recommend any apps, but you might start with Microsoft's ones if you are OK using native calendars for all but the delegate ones).

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for the details.

Comment: @WesleyBland I bet - I've had so many clients really bummed that they had to use the web app to access all sorts of Exchange shared mailboxes and shared calendars - really clunky and it steers people to use Microsoft OS on the endpoints. Same thing Apple does in their ecosystem - so no judgement - just presenting what I see happening.